# How to check if a certain character is present in the String?

Tags: java, string, stringindexoutofbounds

I have wrote a below code to find a keyword `co_e` in the below string, where `_` represents any other character.

It works good if I change the String to `"aaacodebbb"` or `"codexxcode"`
but if I change it to `"xxcozeyycop"` it throws `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
public int countCode(String str) {
    int count = 0;
    String result = "";
    boolean yes = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        // yes = str.charAt(i+3);
        if (str.length() >= 3) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == 'c' && str.charAt(i + 1) == 'o' && str.charAt(i + 3) == 'e')
                count++;
        }
    }
    return (count);
}
```

Comment: no i want to the count of letter c, o then any letter and then e like cope coze core 3rd character can be anything but 1 = c, 2 = o, 3 =can be anything 4 = e

Comment: Your loop goes until str.length(). What is the value of i at the last iteration? And thus what is the value of i + 1 or i + 3? Use your logic and arithmetic skills. What is a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException? Use your reading skills.

Comment: Does `co_e` means `co`(Any string)`e`?

Comment: Do you know regexes? That is another way to show if a certain character or certain character pattern is present in a string. In this case, the regex is `co.e`, where the period is a metacharacter signifying any character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the loop, you are checking accessing i+3. So, you have to stop when `i` is at 4th last position.

Replace `if(str.length()>= 3)` with `if(str.length()>= 3 && str.length() - i >3)`

OR

You can put the following as the first condition in your for loop:

```
if(str.length() - i <=3){
    break;
}
```

Comment: Your first sentence is right. Why not stop the loop then, instead of keeping iterating, and using an if block inside the loop? What's the point of checking the string length inside the loop? Does the string length change at each iteration? Is checking the string length even useful?

Comment: Does it really matter if someone downvoted someone in SO?

Comment: Yes. The OP is struggling with basic loops. And you teach him the bad way of using them. The good whay is `for (int i = 0 i < limit; i++)`. Not `for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) { if (i >= limit) break; }`.

Comment: Downvotes suggest that the answer is not answering the question / wrongly answering the question. If that's not the case & someone is still downvoting without any valid reason, then it raises questions on many subjects.

Comment: How about improving the answer instead of complaining?

Comment: There is a difference b/w answering the question & writing beautiful code.

Comment: Is using the `break` statement in a for loop recommended?

So far, I only use `break` for switch statements.

Comment: Yes, there is no problem in using `break` with `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

Your out-of-bounds error occured in this line:

```
if (str.charAt(i) == 'c' && str.charAt(i + 1) == 'o' && str.charAt(i + 3) == 'e')
```

The error happened at `str.charAt(8)` for `str = "xxcozeyycop"`, because `str.length()` is 11, and `str.charAt(11)` is clearly out of bounds (and so are all `str.charAt(str.length())`)

Here is one possible solution. Note that if `str.length() < 4`, the for loop cannot run, as `i + 3` will always go out of bounds. Also, when `i == str.length() - 4` for all strings longer than four chars, `i+3` would equal the last index of the string, `str.length() - 1`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 3; i++) {
    char c1 = str.charAt(i);
    char c2 = str.charAt(i + 1);
    char c4 = str.charAt(i + 3);

    if (c1 == 'c' && c2 == 'o' && c4 == 'e')
        count++;
}
```